# Intersection and Union with Set and Family of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that set $A = \{ a, b \}$ and family $F = \{ A \}$,

- What is $A \cup F$?
- What is $A \cap F$?

I'm curious about this, since we're comparing sets with families of sets. My hypothesis is that $A \cup F = \{ a, b, \{a, b \}\}$ and $A \cap F = \emptyset$. Thank you!

Comment: $A$ and $F$ are disjoint, so your hypotheses are correct.

Comment: For example, $\{ \{ a , b \}  \} \cup \{ a, b \} = \{ \{ a , b \} ,  a, b \} $.

Answer (score 2):

As you have guessed:

$A \cup F = \{a, b, A\}$
and $A \cap F = \emptyset$.

By definition, the intersection of two sets is a set containing all of the elements contained in both sets. We know that $a$ and $b$ are not in $F$ even though they are in $A$. So, the intersection is the empty set.